# I confuse why my image not showing when running, FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, image

My problem is that my image asset is not showing when I debug the code. That's showing "Format Exception: Message Corrupted there. I think you can see the image below.
[see, the error is there like I say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4aC8.png)

can you help me? to clear the problem :)

> child: Padding(
> padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0, top: 20, bottom: 20),
> child: Expanded(
> child: Row(
> mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
> children: [
> SizedBox(width: 10),
> Image.asset('lib/images/logo_honda.png'),
> Text(
> 'Toyota',
> style: TextStyle(
> color: Color(0xFF077bd7),
> fontSize: 26,
> fontFamily: 'Raleway',
> fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
> letterSpacing: 3,
> ),
> ),
> ],
> ),
> ),
> ),

okay, this is my pubspec.yaml code for the asset :

flutter:

## The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is

## included with your application, so that you can use the icons in

## the material Icons class.

uses-material-design: true

## To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

assets:

- lib/images/logo_honda.png

I have to try many kinds of showing images in Flutter but I can't fix it. I have to try to show images like my project before and that's not help me. This is my first time using VSC, in my project before I used Android Studio, and all projects worked correctly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please try moving the images from lib to main directory for example your image are in  `<project>/lib/images/logo_honda.png` so move it to `<project>/images/logo_honda.png`. Don't forgot to update asset location in pubspec.yaml and if you have many images then you can just type `
...

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/
...
` If you get any error please let me know

Comment: i dont know how, but the image is showing now. Im just reopen the project after 1 day.

Comment: When I got the error "Format Exception: Message Corrupted" in my own project, it got fixed after I ran `flutter clean`. It seems this error doesn't occur due to coding issues, but due to some form of "corrupt" cache.